# How to block until EC2 status check is passed using Python Boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I have the following python code to detect whether an EC2 is really started. But it completes when "instance state" shows running.
which API function should I use to block until EC2 "status check" show "2/2 checks passed"

```
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
instance = ec2.Instance(instanceid)
instance.wait_until_running()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is rare that you would need to wait for the status check to pass.

When an instance enters the *running* state, the machine boots, loads the operating system and generally "runs".

The [EC2 Status Checks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-system-instance-status-check.html) are an independent process that check attributes of the virtual machine. However, your machine is normally running, and you can login to it, well before the status checks show a positive response.

If you *do* wish to wait for the Status Check, there are two waiters that *might* do this, but the documentation is unclear:

- [InstanceStatusOk](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Waiter.InstanceStatusOk)
- [SystemStatusOk](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Waiter.SystemStatusOk)

Comment: good to know running state is enough. my EC2 is ready so fast that I do not believe it is really running. I just want to make sure when the EC2 is running again, it starts to work like usual. Thanks for answering.

Comment: Note that g4dn.xlarge takes about 4 minutes to load before ssh access is available.